# User gets Publicist badge almost daily

Tags: support, badges

I was looking at badges and have stumbled upon [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) badge, it has been awarded 564 times.

Looking through the list of users that got it, one stands out. Lately he gets it almost every day, sometimes more than one. He has ~100 posts and 42 Publicist badges.

The odds of this happening are pretty low in my opinion. Is this normal?

**UPDATE:**

I'd somehow understand that this would be possible, he could be sharing some questions/answers on some Facebook group or G+ community, where people needed help, that would be a possible outcome.

But... I just took the time to look at all the 32 badges he was awarded, and he is involved in **ALL** of them, which is weird.

Even 'weirder' he asked 17 questions, and for all 17 of them he received the badge, and yeah... first 17 badges he got, were his 17 questions, the 15 remaining were rewarded on questions he provided an answer to.

Any update from ♦?

[image]

Comment: @KenY-N It's for him sharing the SO link to others, not for the question/answer itself having a link.

Comment: I've not found the supposed shared url (aka so.com/postid/userid) anywhere for at least the most recent awarded badge.

Comment: 1. Find a 800 views question, copy its link; 2. search for the subject; 3. answer any question (old or not?) on the subject and add: "Check here (paste link) for more info"; 4. Question gets over 1000 views; 5. ???; 6. Profit. Sounds like a plan.

Comment: @DanielGomes That's not how the publicist badge work http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/213575. You that 1000 unique ips click *your link*, not just questions visited, otherwise I should have hundreds of those...

Comment: So I was curious to see if we can see visit information via the data explorer. Turns out we can't. However, this question, in the database, is marked as having 75 views: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341530, while the question has 1099. If it's to do with the data not yet being flushed to the database, that means there's been an influx of approximately 1000 users in the last day? (or however often they flush the view count to DB). Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160574/

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, that doesn't make any sense. I was worried though - thought it wasn't clear enough. Having 1000 unique ips visiting another question through your link is... rare. If one of those questions got around 1k views total, does that mean everyone visited that question through his link?

Comment: Same thing with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326091 and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341535 - All these 1000 views are coming in within a 24-hour window. Either he's running an extremely popular site (which isn't showing up on google), or there's something fishy going on

Comment: The people that can determine what's going on here have been made aware of this post.

Comment: @DanielGomes if you are a [Tim Post](https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/440343103233208320) you could...

Comment: @Rob Yes, that looks normal. The Data Explorer is only updated once a week. You can easily get over 1000 views in a day by posting a link on a popular programming subreddit.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the harm. How is this in any way bad for SO?

Comment: @JDB If it's legit, I see none either. But I can't stop thinking of a lolcats twitter post with a shortened SO url inside... ;)

Comment: One of those questions looks to be way too broad and should be closed as such: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30358687/325727 . The title of the question that stands out because of its "very weird" use of quotes that probably should have been edited out

Comment: Hes not the only one, but perhaps the most prolific.  I can see other names repeated quite often on that list.  If he has a blog and says to the readers "hey guys, check out my SO answer here [link]" then its kosher.  If he has a blog and is loading the answer in a 1x1 pixel iframe so that every visitor "reads" the answer, then its cheating.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: But unless you're a very fervent participant in regular subreddit activities, it's likely you'd be shadowbanned after posting just a couple of links.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I don't recommend spamming a subreddit with links to any one site. People can look at your posting history and see if you're actually participating in the community in other ways, so you will get banned if you're not.

Comment: @JK. SE disallows iframing its content, so they probably wouldn't count such "views"   (since the page wasn't loaded).

Comment: From [list of published questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist?userid=3810333) we can see that there ware 30 of them, and 20 of them have ~1250 views, 5 have ~2500 views, and 5 have ~10,000 views. It is stunning that there is no single question with `4k-8k` range of views.

Comment: Looks like he built some type of bot to up his views, I'd be interested to hear what was/is really going on when it's been looked into.

Comment: Examining [his reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3810333/yurets?tab=reputation&sort=graph) shows two significant drops in reputation.  The drop reasons are both "*User was removed*", meaning some other user who had upvoted many of his posts was removed and their votes cancelled.  Considering *both* of those drops occur immediately after almost the same quantity was gained, I'm guessing he created an (automated?) alt that upvoted his posts.  After it failed twice, he gave up.

Comment: Man, the suspense is killing me, I want to know what's going on

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, has anyone tried asking the guy?

Comment: @cybermonkey But doesn't SE track your account or ip maybe? Wouldn't they limit the views that you can "place" on a question, to like 5 or something?

Comment: Wait! I just looked at a few of those questions, and he has an answer on each question that gets the views...

Comment: @Zizouz212 nice observation. I checked, he is involved in all of them. First all his 17 questions got it, now it's 'time' for the answers.

Comment: @BoltClock You don't need a very significant level of activity to avoid getting banned, in my experience. However we can rule out Reddit because [there's a list of all recent Stack Overflow posts on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/domain/stackoverflow.com/new/) and his don't seem to be there.

Comment: [Announcer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=3810333) | [Booster](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster?userid=3810333) | [Publicist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist?userid=3810333) | [User Badges](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3810333/yurets?tab=activity&sort=badges). Almost all recent badges are Announcer/Booster/Publicist or Popular/Notable/Famous Question.

Comment: @Pshebo Obviously he’s figured out some way to parley a bunch of zero-scoring questions into shiny gold badges through some artifice. Shouldn’t we congratulate him for his cleverness? After all, it wouldn’t work this way if SE didn’t want this to happen, and since it has happened, surely it must be what they want. You can tell that from the Gold Badge description: *“Gold badges recognize **important contributions** from members of the community. They are **rarely awarded.”*** Who could ever argue that this falls outside the purview of rarely awarded recognition for important contributions? 

Comment: @tchrist (it is Pshemo, not Pshebo) "Obviously he’s figured... through some artifice." in that case why number of visitors is not increasing? Is he deleting that link from article after getting a badge and maybe replace it with new one? Also among 1k viewers who clicked such link there has to be someone with SO account able to vote, so even if it would be 1% of viewers each of posted links could generate around 10 votes. I posted my earlier comment because it looks like bot action, which means that SO or knowledge from that post is not promoted, which kind of defeats purpose of that badge.

Comment: @tchrist Currently situation can look like: (1) there exist application - based on user profile, probably Android app (2) which was installed by few thousands of people (3) which creates silent requests to shared link, so user can't even see it (4) link is changed after each application update. That is only a theory, but if case is similar then I don't feel like ***important contributions*** which is promotion of SO or knowledge applies here. I would simply want to know that moderators or SO stuff knows what is going on (details doesn't need to be public), and they are not against it.

Comment: @Pshemo You seem to have missed the ironic smiley at the end of tchrist's comment. As for your question, "Is he deleting that link from article after getting a badge and maybe replace it with new one?", the user admitted to doing exactly that in a comment on [his answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300639/176646): "When I'm done I replace the link with another one, so it doesn't stick there for a long time. Moreover, it is not searchable as it is in closed source. That's why people couldn't find where I placed them. Let's say I offer people to view the link I'm sharing."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I read that comment but offering people "to view the link" doesn't explain much. Lets say I wrote app which opens shared link. Did I *offer* to view it, or *make* people to view it? Anyway I don't have anything against sharing link as long (1) people will be informed where link is going to take them (2) they will have a *choice* to visit it or ignore it without consequences - if this link is part of app, lack of visit can't block any important parts of app (3) they will be able to actually read that post - no browser simulator should be used to generate false visit.

Comment: Hum, tough call. He's not doing anything wrong but he defeated the system completely. He's getting gold badges as fast as bronze ones... Time to get your gold badges guys! Prices are dropping!

Comment: This is still being investigated and discussed.

Comment: @JeremyBanks any update?  Sitting on the edge of my seat here!

Comment: And his halfway to getting yet another one.  This post has gone up by about 60 views in 20 minutes (currently on 486): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815192/android-custom-actionbar-with-search-view

Comment: And he just made it.  The post is now at 1072 votes, up from 486 about 5 hours ago.  That averages out to around 120 views an hour or about 2 views a minute.  I'm impressed.  I'd love to know where his posting these links or how his sharing them? @JeremyBanks can you share?

Comment: @Calcolat given that rate, it _must_ be something like a porn app that lets you bypass a limit or advertisement if you visit the link. :P

Comment: Just a suggestion, but wouldn't it be more appropriate, to award that badge only once... I would't take away the already earned badges of this and other users, but in the future no one gets hurt, when this badge would only be awarded once per user... and it no one cares, if someone "something like cheated" to get one gold-badge (given, that this badge gives no rep-bonus by itself)

Comment: @maze-le The problem with awarding it once only is that that would conflict with TPTB’s goals of getting eyes-on-ads, which is the behavior that that badge is encouraging. I doubt it’s worked out that way in this case, however.

Comment: That's a funny thought @ CodeCaster.  The weird thing is that the couple of times I looked, the views seemed to be increasing at a linear rate.  If he did something like that, I would of expected the traffic would come and go in spurts.  Instead it kept increasing at the same rate, almost like if he had a bot or some sort of system where people were lining up to click the link one after the other.  Of course I only checked a couple of times and only the mods would have the data to know for sure what rate he was sending the traffic at.  Speaking of which, @JeremyBanks where are you? :P

Comment: @Calcolat Waiting for more information from the CMs, who have been pretty busy lately. This isn't very time-sensitive compared with some other issues they have to deal with. Don't worry, it hasn't been forgotten.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. If there are similar occurrences in the future, just flag one of the user's posts with a custom message and we'll investigate.

We appreciate users sharing content with others who may be interested in it. This benefits the community and the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges exist to encourage that. However, attempting to earn them by driving traffic to your links without any reasonable expectation that visitors will be interested is against the spirit of the badges. If a user does this deliberately and repeatedly it becomes an abuse of the system. Depending on the situation, this may result in badges being revoked or other consequences.

In this case, there is clear evidence that very few of the the tens of thousands of views generated on those questions were from readers who had any interest in the content. The badges will be revoked.

Comment: wrt _evidence_, it would probably make sense to use [anonymous feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-feedback/info) for this. At a scale of "tens of thousands of views" these stats could be quite reliable, eg to compare these in posts that gave badges _organically_ against suspected ones

Comment: Thank you for the update!

Comment: Wondering if @Marko will ask now: "User gets [Famous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=3810333) badge almost weekly"...

Comment: @DanielGomes Lets not forget about [Notable Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question?userid=3810333) and maybe even [Popular Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=3810333)

Comment: I'm not sure why most if not all the Famous/Notable/Popular badges weren't revoked as well?