# Do entry level badges encourage superfluous questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, new-users

I've used stack overflow as a reference for a long time but am now just starting to become an active user. In my first week of use I've noticed that the entry-level badges (student, scholar, etc...) encourage new users to generate content. I can't help but wonder if many times new users aren't just asking questions to get badges as opposed to actually seeking answers. Are these questions a burden on the people actually answering/moderating them?

I do understand that the badges encourage users to learn by doing, I just wonder if perhaps there would be less superfluous questions generated if the entry-level badges did not encourage new users to ask questions even if they don't really have one.

Comment: A lot of times, "new users" aren't new users until they have a question they need an answer to anyway. I doubt that these badges are convincing people to sign up and ask poor quality questions. I would say an easy way to argue this is that the "Informed" badge is _extremely_ easy to get- Even easier than asking a question! Yet there are plenty of new users who _don't_ bother to go get it, because their interest is not in the badges, but instead in getting answers to their questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe this is actually a problem.

Yeah, it's easy to ask a question, and it's easy to accept an answer on a question. But I think a lot of these new users don't even realize they can get badges for these things until they've received one.

If they were just trying to gain badges, more of them would have the "Informed" badge- All you have to do is take the tour. Boom, badge. Far easier than asking a question and getting an upvote on it.

Users just posting these things for the badges would do one of two things: Post a ton of terrible questions, or take advice to improve their question to get the badge more easily. Those doing the first action would likely get question banned rather quickly. Those doing the second *are doing exactly what we want them to do.* Those doing the first... Well, they're gonna have a bad time with the site.

If these users are just going for badges, that could end up being a good thing- If they are the better of the two badge hunters and actually improve, then going on to earn other badges will teach them about the site. Hopefully, this will mold them into a constructive member of the community.

Answer (score 2):

Badges are awarded for *positive* actions.  Once you figure out you can only earn "Peer Pressure" once, it becomes all about generating *positively scoring* content.  And that's hard for many new users regardless of their motivations.  So I don't think that the rush to get badges like ["Curious"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious) (Ask a good question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record) will generate (additional) bad content.  **Generating good content is a must for most badges**, and some (like "Curious" or tag badges) even penalize users for bad content.

Besides, real badge hunters often try to go after "easier" badges like ["Autobiographer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer), ["Fanatic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic), or [(apparently) "Publicist"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300470/user-gets-publicist-badge-almost-daily).  These kinds of badges do not rely on new content, so they won't flood SO with bad content.

Comment: badges also teach users about features of the site - do Peer Pressure helps teach users that they can delete bad content and will get the rep they lost back.

Comment: Good point. I suppose in the end users will only be penalized for bad questions.