# How does one get multiple Publicist badges at the same time?

Tags: discussion, badges

According to the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), the **Publicist badge** is a gold badge granted when a user:

> Shares a link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.

Excellent. I didn't even know such a badge existed when [I got my first one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist?userid=3597276) a few days ago.

A more detailed description of this badge is provided in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68505/300177):

> Take the link from the share option directly underneath the question
>   and then share this specially tailored link (it contains your user ID
>   to identify you as the source) pretty much anywhere you like, to
>   encourage other people to visit the link (and thus drive traffic to
>   the site).
>
> This could include Facebook, Twitter, any other social networking site
>   or your blog, for example. But could extend to non-web methods, maybe
>   sneakily write it on the whiteboards around your school / Uni /
>   workplace, directly tell others you work / learn with, give it to with
>   your mates down the pub, and so on...

**Question:** How did [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6998123/mega6382) manage to nab [SIX Publicist badges at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist?userid=6998123)?

[image]

**Duplicate note:** I did see this related post: [User gets Publicist badge almost daily](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300470/3597276)

However, there's no actual answer there (it just says flag such cases for review). Plus, that question is from 3 years ago. Plus, it was about Publicist badges granted over the course of multiple days. This question is about the same badge granted at the same time.

Comment: The batch job could've fired off and determined six questions which qualified the user for the badge. Probably the most reasonable explanation.

Comment: The answer I'm hoping for is a technique that I could apply at an industrial scale :-)

Comment: Luck is a technique.  It's not industrial scale, but it can result in windfalls like this.  Besides that, it's still fairly black-box on how this badge family truly behaves.

Comment: I have a long way to go before I catch up to [Jon Skeet's 620+ gold badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). This might be what I need to take him out.

Comment: Author around 450 great answers, and that'll be a start.

Comment: Maybe an account merge?

Comment: *"The answer I'm hoping for is a technique that I could apply at an industrial scale"*, sorry to disappoint. xD

Comment: Catch up to 620+ Gold badges :D i am happy with my one gold badge

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let me explain. I did not get all these at the same time, this happened over the span of 2 years, what happened today was that I was trying to add an additional email address to my account and ended up replacing my primary email address with the new one, which fired an automated account merge and I lost all my badges.
 So, I contacted the SO team about this and this was their reply:

[image]