# Unable to access chat, login form not working correctly either

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, chat, login

When I visit chat whilst being logged in on the main site, I get this error page https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

But if I visit a specific chat room, it says

> You must be logged in to talk. See the FAQ for more information.

And when I click the login button it redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add, and it is shown as:

[image]

And if I try to login by clicking Google, and click OK, it redirects me to the homepage. But I am still not able to log in to chat. And if I try to login by using email and password, I get this error.

> This email is in use by a different account. To initiate a merge of multiple accounts, consult this help center article.

But I am using the same email as is being used for my account. I even tried clearing the cookies and changing browsers, the same thing.

**Edit:** I am able to access chat from my office computer(where I was already logged in). But not from anywhere else, not even by using a different browser on that office computer.

**Edit 2:** I have sent 2 emails to SO team and have posted this question and still no help. Why? Please, at least respond, even if its just to say we can't help.

**Edit 3:** Now I was automatically logged out from my work pc too, and am unable to login to chat from there either.

Comment: Is this your profile? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2394254/mega6382

Comment: @BhargavRao yes thats my profile

Comment: I just pinged you from a chatroom, did you get that ping?

Comment: @YvetteColomb on my phone, yes.

Comment: can you reply to it?

Comment: highly unlikely but maybe you registered your account initially with your google account and recently someone has used your email address for a normal account? not sure how the different authentications interact with each other

Comment: @WhatsThePoint There are 2 email addresses associated with my account and also 2 login from google for those same emails. So, that is not the reason.

Comment: Do you have a lot of comments in chat? How important is it for you to keep your chat history?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, I do have a lot of comments in chat, I have been quite regular in PHP chat for a while now. And I would really like to keep those along with my chat user id, as it is being used to define me as admin for bot in a couple of rooms.

Comment: @mega6382 we're going to need the community team to step in. All we can do is destroy your chat user and then you will recreate one next time you're in chat, but this will also destroy all your contributions.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I have been hoping that SO team will step in for over 2 weeks now, but they haven't even replied to me yet. If you think you can implore to them on my behalf to look into this, I would be really grateful.

Comment: @YvetteColomb And there is probably a bigger problem with my account, as there was a merging of my account a while back, and I am sure that that has something to do with this, reference https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365666/how-does-one-get-multiple-publicist-badges-at-the-same-time/365669#365669

Comment: @mega6382 we've officially messaged the community team (we've also pinged them in chat). Ping us if it's not fixed in a couple of days.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @mega6382 yw, there's other mods working on it behind the scenes

Comment: @YvetteColomb Now, I cant even access chat from my phone. So, if you can get this message to Madara Uchiha and tell him that he can try " invalidating all sessions" or whatever he was saying.

Comment: @mega6382 will do.

Comment: @mega6382 Done, try it now?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha nope, still not working. :/

Comment: Things *should* be back to working now, I've left you a message in chat. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by the mighty @balpha.

Try not to sacrifice more than 2 goats at a time next time, it causes problems.