# Why am I not logged into Stack Overflow chat?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, login

Every time I attempt to enter chat on Stack Overflow, it either tells me I am not logged in, or I am presented with this [error message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/). I tested entering the chat on StackExchange and Mathematics, and I was logged in, so this problem appears to be specific to Stack Overflow.

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368195/unable-to-access-chat-login-form-not-working-correctly-either) is similar, but it does not appear to explain what the issue was, and it seems a moderator had to step in and fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like something fishy is going on here. [This](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4413591/isaiah) is your chat profile. I can access it fine, but when I try to refresh it from the parent site, that operation fails. I'm not a chat expert, and I don't have developer access anyway, so I'll wait for reinforcements to arrive.

Comment: @Cody The last message was 1828d ago and they weren't more than a handful of messages anyway, so one option is to just delete the chat account and then when Isaiah tries to join chat again it will re-create a chat user that is actually in sync. with a correct main user... (usually more expedient that trying to get a dev involved :p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed some data that was out of sync (and wouldn't sync properly) between the chat user and the parent user account on SO. Should be working now.

Comment: Was this a problem that only affected this specific user's chat profile, or were there other users affected?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it only affected this user (and I can't get into the exact reasons here).

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the response, but I am still having same issues. I tried logging out and then back in, but it keeps acting as if I am not logged in, and when I press the login button again, it brings me to the stackoverflow home page. (Before I tried logging out, I kept getting returned to the same error page as before.)

Comment: @Isaiah can you try again please?

Comment: It is working now, thanks.